# I have a rogue icon in a list I cant control

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

on my contact page "http://findgirvin.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Contact"

the phone icon doesn't center when brought down to mobile screen size. I rewrote the code multiple times. Its a MDL List. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please create a minimal [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or jsfiddle of your code in question? It would be also good to know what you have tried and which mediaqueries you're using. Posting your css could also help to understand. With-out seeing your code it's not possible to help.

Comment: ok I threw the code into a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nkyn5y88m4

Comment: your codesandbox isn't working, there aren't any index.js file to begin with, can you please edit so we can help you more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the site.

I don't know how to solve it 'the mdl UI way' since I haven't used it.

But you can add your own CSS to the span of the `mdl-list__item-primary-content` class, like:

```
.mdl-list__item .mdl-list__item-primary-content > span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If I use flexbox method to center horizontally of a column flex.

Don't forget to add media queries for small screen only.